# nginx ffmpeg mpegts http

Tags: http, nginx, ffmpeg, live

i can't understand how to serve .ts files from nginx.
for hls it works without problems (m3u8).

http://127.0.0.1/hls/stream_name.m3u8

http://127.0.0.1/stream_name

I tried to compile nginx with the 2 modules:

nginx-live-module

nginx-ts-module

It works in part, if I send a stream it works, if I send for example 10 it doesn't work.

ffmpeg -re -f concat -safe 0 -i stream.txt -c copy -map 0 -f mpegts "http://127.0.0.1/stream_name?buffer_size=1048576"

with VLC I open the stream and it works but if I try to open more streams it doesn't open even if ffmpeg is sending to the nginx server.

what am I doing wrong?

```
user  www;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 300000;
events {
    worker_connections  16000;
    use epoll;
        accept_mutex on;
        multi_accept on;
}

error_log  logs/error.log  notice;

http {
    live_zone zone=foo:100m;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            live foo;
            live_methods GET POST;

            # enable endless request body
            client_max_body_size 0m;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try this https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/

Comment: is not i need this thx for reply

i need to push mpegts http to nginx and play mpegts http.
push is not problem, if push 10 stream are ok but if play not all work

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, I hope you found the answers.

You need to compile with rtmp module.
https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module

Take a look at the guide to help you config it.
http://nginx-rtmp.blogspot.com/

PD: What version of nginx were you using? I have tried to compile using "live module" but I get errors.